# Referencing an object (class) within a thread fails

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, class

**Referencing an object (class) within a thread fails**

I have an object ("a vb class") that needs to run on a separate thread and communicate with the U/I.

Even using sample code, I cannot get the object to run within a thread. I demonstrate this problem with two examples. The first calls a function within the form and it works perfectly. The second creates an object and performs the same calls, but fails. 

**example #1 [working] (Called within a form)**

```
 Private Delegate Sub FuctionToBeRunInThreadDelegate

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Console.WriteLine("Thread sample within FORM")

    Dim Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf FuctionToBeRunInThread)
    Thread.Start()

    Console.WriteLine("Thread sample within FORM completed")

 End Sub

 Public Sub FuctionToBeRunInThread()

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Console.WriteLine("Inside new thread....")
        Me.Invoke(New FuctionToBeRunInThreadDelegate(AddressOf FuctionToBeRunInThread))
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("oFuctionToBeRunInThread")
    End If

  End Sub
```

**The output to the console when the function is called within a form is:**
Thread sample within FORM
Thread sample within FORM completed
Inside new thread....
oFuctionToBeRunInThread

This is what I expected. The thread has started asynchronously. Ended very quickly, and the function knows that it is within a thread.

**example #2 [non-working] (Calling same function but this time within an object)**
In my second example, I use an external file containing a class and create the thread in the same manner. 

Here is the main form:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Console.WriteLine("Thread sample using object started.")

    Dim oEngine As New objTest()
    Dim oThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf oEngine.oFuctionToBeRunInThread)
    oThread.Start()

    Console.WriteLine("Thread sample using object completed.")


End Sub
```

Here is the external file containing the class definition:

```
   Public Class objTest

   Private Delegate Sub oFuctionToBeRunInThreadDelegate()

   Public Sub oFuctionToBeRunInThread()

        If frmInitial.InvokeRequired Then
            Console.WriteLine("Inside new thread....")
            frmInitial.Invoke(New oFuctionToBeRunInThreadDelegate(AddressOf oFuctionToBeRunInThread))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("oFuctionToBeRunInThread")
        End If

    End Sub
   End Class
```

In this case, the output is demonstrating that the function is not running in a separate thread. **It is as follows:** 

Thread sample using object started.
Thread sample using object completed.
oFuctionToBeRunInThread



**SUMMARY:** When the thread creates the object, it appears that the object is not actually running inside of a thread or else form.InvokeRequired would be true. I have other more complex examples where this is strongly verified and evidenced, but I provided these two as a very simple demonstration of my problem.
How can I have a thread "own" a series of individual objects so that the objects are run asynchronously and can independently report back to the U/I?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is a Default instance of form in VB.Net but not in C#, WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/there-is-a-default-instance-of-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c-why)

Comment: You are yet another victim of the last paragraph in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Hans, it might be a duplicate... perhaps to a more discerning eye or understanding. I'm not able to see how they are the same. Thank you for the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after debugging your code, it appears that frmInitial.InvokeRequired is failing to execute correctly.

=======================================================

so am back again (with a solution of course):

```
Public Class frmInitial

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Console.WriteLine("event started")

        Dim obj As New ObjTest()
        Dim threadobj As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf obj.dosomework)
        threadobj.Name = "debugme"

        'passing the current form reference to the thread function
        threadobj.Start(Me)

        Console.WriteLine("event completed")
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: screen snapshot]

```
Public Class ObjTest
        Private Delegate Sub dosomeworkDelegate(ByVal f As Form)

        Public Sub dosomework(ByVal f As Form)
            ' Check if the form can be accessed from the current thread.
            If Not f.InvokeRequired Then
                ' Access the form directly.
                Console.WriteLine("delegate executed")
                f.Controls("textbox1").Text = "thread invoked successfuly"
            Else
                ' Marshal to the thread that owns the form. 
                Dim del As dosomeworkDelegate = AddressOf dosomework
                Dim param As Object() = {f}
                Console.WriteLine("executing delegate")
                f.BeginInvoke(del, param)
            End If
        End Sub

End Class
```

believe me its way better than studying for my numerical analysis exam :-)

Comment: That is true. When the function is a member of the form "Me.InvokeRequired" returns True. However, in the case where the function is a member of a class, "frmInitial.InvokeRequired" returns false. 

Any idea why this is? I am really stumped. 

Thank you for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I am going to try this tomorrow. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: **Thank you** -- This works. I am still a little confused about threading overall, but I believe that I can fold this into the project. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just an update... I now have (up to) ten dynamically generated threads, each doing complex math, each updating the screen independantly... I hope that you destroyed that numerical analysis exam!

Comment: why the fuss after all, avoid using threads unless substantially needed. by the way that's lots of work, am not a pro but i got a vision when it comes to coding, no offense, but it seems that your trying to get rid of your work by assigning it to me :-) am still a grad, well senior grad, with no job;

Comment: Sarepta, I am genuinely sorry that you feel that way. I was just seeking advice. Your response was well above what I was expecting. Thank you again.