# reference uninstansiated objects in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i'm having to learn VB.net for a new job having previously been a C# guy. I just come across an interesting feature of VB.net. I can reference objects on a second form that has not been instatiated!

So from Form1 i can get the text property of textbox1 on Form2 as follows

```
Dim txt As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
```

Can anyone explain how this works? Are all forms instatiated at the start of the program and then their visibility is toggled throughout the program lifespan?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is a Default instance of form in VB.Net but not in C#, WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/there-is-a-default-instance-of-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms in VB are a special case. The compiler generates a strongly-typed list of forms in the  [`My.Forms` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the `My` namespace. Each form is exposed as a property `My.Forms.TheNameOfTheForm`. These properties always return valid instances – i.e. if a form hasn’t been instantiated before, it will when you first use the property.

So far, so good.

But Microsoft also made the brain-dead (!) decision of importing the properties from the `My.Forms` object by default, *everywhere*, and there’s nothing you can do. Superficially, this is for backwards compatibility reasons to VB6 but that’s nonsense since VB7 (.NET 1.0) didn’t have this feature, it only came later.

But just to clarify:

> Are all forms instatiated at the start of the program …?

No, luckily not. They are instantiated the first time you access the property.

Comment: +1. But Microsoft **did** add the feature for backwards compatibility with VB6. They missed it from the first VB.Net, but they added more features in the next couple of versions to increase backwards compatibility.

Comment: Also worth noting that the form will re-instiate automatically when you reference a property, even after you have set the reference to nothing.

Comment: This makes conversion from VB6 very easy, but just takes extra care from the programmer to NOT use this feature by mistake.