# Append text to a RichTextBox from another class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, append, richtextbox

I have a `Form` (ClientGUI) that has a `RichTextBox`. What I want to do is to append text to this RichTextBox from a Sub located in another class (MyQuickFixApp). I know that the Sub works, because the debugger go through, but it doesn't append the text to my `RichTextBox`.

How do I do that ?

Thanks for you help !

---

ClientGUI.vb :

```
Imports QuickFix
Imports QuickFix.Transport
Imports QuickFix.Fields

Public Class ClientGUI
    Dim initiator As SocketInitiator

    Public Sub ClientGUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim filename As String = "Resources/initiator.cfg"
        Dim settings As New SessionSettings(filename)
        Dim myApp As New MyQuickFixApp()

        Dim storeFactory As New FileStoreFactory(settings)
        Dim logFactory As New FileLogFactory(settings)

        initiator = New SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ConnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ToolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "Establishing connection..."
        ToolStripDropDownButton1.Image = My.Resources.Connecting
        initiator.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisconnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DisconnectToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ToolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "Disconnecting..."
        ToolStripDropDownButton1.Image = My.Resources.Disconnecting
        initiator.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

MyQuickFixApp.vb :

```
Imports QuickFix
Imports QuickFix.Transport
Imports QuickFix.Fields

Public Class MyQuickFixApp
    Inherits MessageCracker : Implements IApplication

    Dim _session As Session = Nothing

    Public Sub FromAdmin(message As Message, sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.FromAdmin
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("")
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("IN (ADMIN): " + message.ToString())

        Try
            Crack(message, sessionID)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("")
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("==Cracker exception==")
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString())
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FromApp(message As Message, sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.FromApp
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("")
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("IN (APP): " + message.ToString())

        Try
            Crack(message, sessionID)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("")
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("==Cracker exception==")
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString())
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub ToApp(message As Message, sessionId As SessionID) Implements IApplication.ToApp
        Try
            Dim possDupFlag As Boolean = False
            If (message.Header.IsSetField(Tags.PossDupFlag)) Then
                possDupFlag = Converters.BoolConverter.Convert(message.Header.GetField(Tags.PossDupFlag))
            End If
            If (possDupFlag) Then
                Throw New DoNotSend()
            End If
        Catch ex As FieldNotFoundException
            ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("OUT (APP): " + message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnCreate(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnCreate
        '_session = Session.LookupSession(sessionID)
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Session created - " + sessionID.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnLogon(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogon
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Logon - " + sessionID.ToString())
        ClientGUI.ToolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "Connected"
        ClientGUI.ToolStripDropDownButton1.Image = My.Resources.Connected
        'MsgBox("onlogon")
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnLogout(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogout
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Logout - " + sessionID.ToString())
        ClientGUI.ToolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "Disconnected"
        ClientGUI.ToolStripDropDownButton1.Image = My.Resources.Disconnected
    End Sub

    Public Sub ToAdmin(message As Message, sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.ToAdmin
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("OUT (ADMIN): " + message.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnMessage(message As FIX42.Heartbeat, sessionID As SessionID)
        ClientGUI.RichTextBox1.AppendText("HEARTBEAT")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the code in `MyQuickFixApp` class access to the **default instance** of your `ClientGUI`, not the instance which is actually running, each time you write `ClientGUI.(...)`.

See this thread [Why is there a default instance of every form in VB.Net but not in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698538/2387010) for more information about default instance, which is something you should avoid to use.

So you could add a parameter in the  `MyQuickFixApp` class constructor :

```
 Public Class MyQuickFixApp
    Inherits MessageCracker : Implements IApplication

    Dim _clientGUI As ClientGUI = Nothing
    Public Sub New(cltGui As ClientGUI)
        _clientGUI = cltGui
    End sub

    (...)
End class
```

Then, replace in the `MyQuickFixApp` class all the `ClientGUI.(...)`, with `_clientGUI.(...)` to be sure to access to the correct instance.

And finally, initialize your `MyQuickFixApp` class in `ClientGUI` like this:

```
Dim myApp As New MyQuickFixApp(me)
```

Note that this code, you can only access to the method of the class in the `Form_Load` event. This variable should be declared in the class and initialized in the form_load if you want to access it later from the `ClientGUI` form.

```
Public Class ClientGUI
    Dim initiator As SocketInitiator
    Dim myApp As MyQuickFixApp()

    Public Sub ClientGUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       (...)
       myApp =New MyQuickFixApp(Me)
       (...)
    End Sub

     (...)
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I understood how it works, and now everything is perfect. Thank you for your help. However, I had to set the parameter Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to False.

Answer (score 0):

In Form

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();

        tc.addComment(richTextBox1);
    }
```

In Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TestClass
{
    public void addComment(RichTextBox rt) 
    {
        rt.Text = rt.Text + Environment.NewLine + "My Dynamic Text";
    }
}
```

you can do it same in VB.net also

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear, it is not really what I want to do. I added the code I have in my message. The problem is that when I want to append text from MyQuickFixApp.vb it doesn't work.

Comment: How you are passing "ClientGUI" object of your form to "MyQuickFixApp.vb" class ?