# Using FormName.Show() in a VB.NET application

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, conventions

In a VB.NET application, what is the proper way to open a form?

```
Dim f1 as new Form1()
f1.Show()
```

or

```
Form1.Show()
```

I have inherited a codebase that is nearly 100% the latter.

What exactly is happening here?  From what I understand, this should be an error considering Form1 is never initialized with a `new`.  Does .NET automatically instantiate an object for all of your forms?

What are the issues that can be caused by this, specifically memory issues?
Is it bad practice to use Forms like this?

Comment: This is specific to Visual Basic.

Comment: @ByteBlast Does C# not allow the second case?

Comment: @ByteBlast Tested it myself, was unaware they were different.  Question's updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is already a question on this - [Why is there a default instance of every form in VB.Net but not in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/there-is-a-default-instance-of-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c-why)

It seems it's a vb specific syntax - in c# you'd certainly need to instantiate a new instance of the form, and even in vb I'd suggest that would be best practice...after all you are dealing with an instance of the form.  I'm actually surprised that vb.net lets you call show as a static method on a form...it just doesn't compute for me

Comment: There's a lot of things about VB.NET that don't compute for me :)  It probably has to do with the roots of VB.NET being in VB (though the two are not the same).

Comment: It was done that way to match how VB6 worked.  VB.Net creates "default" instances of the forms with the same name as the form class.  I think it causes more problems than it solves!!