# Disable "default instance" in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've started doing some basic win forms work in VB 2010 and I'm really bothered by the [default instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698538/794234) feature.  Is there a way I can disable it entirely and just use the classes like ordinary classes?

Comment: No.  It is a feature added to make it easier for hobbyists and those resisting the change from VB6 to NET.  If you dont like it, dont use it.

Comment: Plutonix is right - you can simply ignore it in your code.

Comment: Congratulations on recognizing it as a horrible feature! VB programmers who use it without realizing what they're doing are doing themselves no favors.

Comment: @Plutonix it's hard to "not use" sometimes.  It shows up in all my intellisense and doesn't break my build if I make a mistake.

Comment: Just avoid to name variables as a types or closely to them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to the form's constructor. That will prevent the default instance being created. You will need to have a call to InitializeComponent to layout the controls.

```
Sub New(junk As Object)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```