# datagridview rows are zero after leaving form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

For context, I have an app that does draft picks for our baseball fantasy league. It records the picks as people make them. I want to add a form with a blank grid that fills in with the picks as they are made and output to my TV. In my main form I have this simple code:

```
Private Sub SetUpPickBoard()

    Dim frmPickBoard As New frmResults
    frmPickBoard.Show()

End Sub
```

Then, in my form load for frmResults, I manually build a datagridview like such:

```
Private Sub frmResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim rsPlayers As DataTable
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT ID,DrafterName FROM tblDrafters ORDER BY DraftOrder"
    rsPlayers = frmMain.DataAccess.GetDataTable(strSQL)
    intDrafterCount = rsPlayers.Rows.Count
    For intDrafters = 0 To intDrafterCount - 1
        dgvPickBoard.Columns.Add("Drafter" & intDrafters.ToString, rsPlayers.Rows(intDrafters).Item("DrafterName"))
    Next
    For intCtr = 0 To 22
        Dim dgrNewRow As New DataGridViewRow
        dgrNewRow.HeaderCell.Value = (intCtr + 1).ToString
        dgvPickBoard.Rows.Add(dgrNewRow)
    Next
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    MsgBox(dgvPickBoard.Rows.Count & "-" & dgvPickBoard.Columns.Count)
End Sub
```

The msgbox at the end displays (correctly) 23-10

Then it returns to the main form. Then, in the code for making a pick, I simply tried to change the text of one of the cells in that form with the picked name.

```
rsResults.datagridview1.rows(rownumber).cells(columnnumber).value=strPickedName
```

I get index out range error. The rowcount is now 0, as is the columns. Even if I call a function in the frmResults form and pass in the row,column and text values, the datagridview still has zero rows/columns. I don't want to have to rebuild a whole grid from the DB every time I make a pick if possible.

So why is my datagridview 'empty'? It is still displayed in the form. Did I lose the reference to the rows when it left the load function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had issues with another form I was trying to manipulate, and I finally stumbled on the issue. The answer is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367853/vb-net-how-to-change-a-property-of-a-form-element-from-another-module). Basically, referencing a form by the form name essentially gives you a 'copy' of sorts of your actual form. I changed the reference of the form from frmResults to the object I created when I instanced the form of frmPickBoard (I had to move the definition to a global level, of course). I was then able to access and manipulate all controls in the form I created.

Comment: It doesn't give you a copy. It gives you the default instance. The default instance is still an instance, just like the instance you created. They are both instances but they are different objects, so making changes to one will have no effect on the other.

Comment: *"I had to move the definition to a global level"*. Hopefully what you actually mean is that you made the declaration at the class level. "Global" generally means accessible to the entire application, so public in a module or something like that. There's no need for this variable to be accessible outside the main form, as far as I can tell, so a private field in the same type would be the correct option.

Comment: So you get the default instance, and then another instance you instantiate, effectively creating "a 'copy' of sorts". And perhaps I wanted to reference this form from another form without accessing the main form for the reference to it. Whatever. I think everyone understood I meant "outside the method level". I even included the link to the exact details so my paraphrasing didn't cause any confusion. You're not being helpful, just obtuse.

Comment: If you think that using accurate terminology is obtuse rather than helpful, then you're are likely going to hinder your own progress. I always find it slightly amusing to see beginners who are so determined to not admit to getting something wrong that they'll argue with someone who's been doing this for two and a half decades rather than just learn something and move on. I've been a beginner and I've helped many a beginner but sure, you definitely know more about this than I do.

Comment: *'effectively creating "a 'copy' of sorts"'*. Nope. The default instance is no more or less a copy than the instance you created is a copy. They are both instances of the same class created by invoking the same constructor. If you create4d multiple instances yourself, would any of those be copies of the others? I would hope that you would recognise that they are not, so you ought to recognise that the default instance is not a copy either, effectively or otherwise.

Comment: *"perhaps I wanted to reference this form from another form without accessing the main form"*. Then you should have used the default instance in both cases rather than neither, as I already pointed out. That's the very reason that default instances exist. You don't have to do so - what you're doing is not wrong - but if you wanted to do it the "proper" way, i.e. engage in best practice, then you would be going via the main form. If you're going to take a shortcut then why not take the full shortcut instead of the half measure that is more complex than necessary for no good reason?

Comment: I am 55. I've been programming since I was 17 and I did a paper route to earn money to buy a commodore 64. I intentionally used laymen's language (hence the single quotes around copy) and linked to the exact explanation with the "accurate terminology" so there was no misunderstanding my paraphrasing of the solution. Just stop. I'll repeat. You are not being helpful. You are being borderline a jerk. And for the record, I actually made it a property just in case I needed to reference it from another form. And "accurately" speaking, class level ie property IS global to the class.

Comment: This is a programmers' site. No need to use layman's terms here. Better not to, because you simply muddy the waters for no good reason. If you use precise language, there's no need for interpretation. As for experience, if you don't know how default instances work, I can only assume (and hope) that you're a relative beginner with VB.NET. Anyway, this discussion is likely going nowhere and is probably inappropriate in these comments so I'll make my exit.

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be, when you click on the header cell of the row, you get the ColumnIndex of -1.

Following code, catches that error and ignores it else it takes the header text of the column.

I used a different class for the sql query and i filled a DataTable with it, that is better to handle

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT ID,DrafterName FROM tblDrafters ORDER BY ID"
    SQL.ExedQuey(strSQL)
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Return
    intDrafterCount = SQL.recordCount
    For intDrafters = 0 To intDrafterCount - 1
        dgvPickBoard.Columns.Add("Drafter" & intDrafters.ToString, SQL.DBDT.Rows(intDrafters).Item("DrafterName"))
    Next
    For intCtr = 0 To 22
        Dim dgrNewRow As New DataGridViewRow
        dgrNewRow.HeaderCell.Value = (intCtr + 1).ToString
        dgvPickBoard.Rows.Add(dgrNewRow)
    Next
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    MsgBox(dgvPickBoard.Rows.Count & "-" & dgvPickBoard.Columns.Count)
End Sub

Private Sub dgvPickBoard_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPickBoard.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then
        'Headercell clicked ignore
    Else
        dgvPickBoard.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = dgvPickBoard.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Datagridview filled]

Comment: This code is correct, but completely unrelated to my issue. I wasn't clicking on the datagridview. I was trying to set values for the cells programmatically, so there was no value for columnindex, or at least not one I was evaluating. The issue was I created a new instance of the form, but I was referencing the default instance of the form, not realizing that a default instance was even created.