# VB.NET Forms App Architecture

Tags: vb.net

I'm a bit confused on exactly how the architecture for a VB.NET forms app actually works.

I've noticed in others' code, lines that read a little like this:

```
If frmMain.someBooleanProperty Then
```

but, I'm a bit confused because `someBooleanProperty` is then defined as an instance variable (i.e., as `Public someBooleanProperty As Boolean` in `frmMain`). How is it being referenced statically to access an instance variable? Is this just bad coding practice?

Comment: if `frmMain` is an instance of `Form18` then it is an instance object variable. if `frmMain` *is* the class name then a default instance is being used which is not usually a good idea

Comment: `frmMain` is defined as `Public Class frmMain`.... so shouldn't `frmMain` be a reference to that class?

Comment: in that case, when it is used VB creates an instance which happens to have the same name - this is called the default instance and generally leads to trouble in various cases.

Comment: Sounds like a terribly flawed design.... But thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It was added to VS2005 to be compatible with the way that VB6 worked.  Its *not* a good idea but allows tinkers to get code running without having to understand OOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons of backwards compatibility, VB.NET **automatically creates an instance of every Form**. This instance is accessible through a global property **which has the same name as the Form class itself**.

More details can be found here:

- [Why is there a default instance of every form in VB.Net but not in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-is-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c)