# How does VB.NET execute a non-shared method without an instance?

Tags: vb.net, instance, .net-2.0

I noticed that I can call a method that is not shared by just writing `Class.Method`. Coming from C#-development I don't get how this is working. The method is correctly executed even though it writes to and reads from instance variables.

example method:

```
Public Class FormMain Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Friend Sub Foo()
        'do instance stuff here
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Private Sub Bar()
        FormMain.Foo() 'this works!?
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is VB.NET using the only instance if there is only one? If not, how else is this working?

Comment: Some background to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-is-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c

Comment: And if you want an advice, stick with the good practices learned in C#

Comment: Forms act differently...