# How does visual know what form I want?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

So I have the folowing code for a form.

```
Public Class tab
     Public personas, formaciones, avisos, cursos As List(Of Object)
     [Lots of Code]
End class
```

On another form I want the `formaciones` List, so I can just:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = tab.formaciones
```

And it works, perfectly.

But.. How?

`tab` is a class, not an instance of it, but vb is able to understand that I want the instance of that class.

What happen if there are mor than one `tab` open? How does it work internally?

Comment: You could [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c). VB create an instance of each form for you, that's why it works. But you would have to specify which instance you want if you have multiple forms.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar actually, vb does create instance "on the fly" for each forms.

Comment: @the_lotus One more reason to stay away from VB as far as possible and learn a proper language in the first place... Anyway: In this example, `tab` is not a form?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, yes poor naming. Even more when you consider that `tab` is my main form. So yes, it have an instance. But how does visual know that Im referring to that instance when I'm just using the class name?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I prefer C#, but work inforces vb use so...

Comment: @the_lotus And if I had multiple instances and I wrote the same line, which one would it access?

Comment: @Aimnox an instance with the same name as the class is generated. If you had multiple instance, you would have a variable for each so it would all depend on which variable you chose to use.

Comment: @the_lotus but it doesn't generate a new instance, it takes the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of a default **application framework** that is enabled when creating VB.NET **WinForms** applications.

Its intent was to help the migration from VB6 so it creates singletons of each form.

If you want different instances, you can disable/ignore the framework and write your own start up methods.

More details:

Singleton forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233839.aspx

Enable/disable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17k74w0c(v=vs.100).aspx

Full article: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx