# Property in Dialog is never set before the dialog closes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I open a dialog with 2 buttons. Those buttons should set a property to a value and then close the form. My main form should then grab that property. Whenever I try to grab the value it's always blank.

My Main Form

```
    Using SelectNextForm As New TubeSelectTo()
    SelectNextForm.Focus()
        If TubeSelectTo.ShowDialog(currentWO, status) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
             MessageBox.Show(SelectNextForm.numberOfBins)
        End If
```

The dialog

```
Private numberBins As String

Public Overloads Function ShowDialog(ByVal woID As String, ByVal currStatus As ResourceStatus) As DialogResult

    Return Me.ShowDialog()

End Function

Public ReadOnly Property numberOfBins() As String
    Get
        Return numberBins
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    numberBins = "1"
    DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    numberBins = "2"
    DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
End Sub
```

So why isn't my property being set?

Comment: You need to show us the `numberBins` declaration aswell. Have you tested this in a completely new project?

Comment: If "the dialog" code is for `TubeSelectTo` you are asking a different form (`SelectNextForm`) for the bins than what set them.  Also, in that code, `numberBins` appears from nowhere

Comment: @Plutonix you got it. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Vincent has a fine answer already

Comment: Sorry, just realized I accidentally stole your answer @Plutonix.

Comment: Its not theft...it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
If TubeSelectTo.ShowDialog(currentWO, status) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
```

You are using the [**default instance**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698538/3740093) of the `TubeSelectTo` form, rather than the `SelectNextForm` instance that you created.

Change it to:

```
If SelectNextForm.ShowDialog(currentWO, status) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
```