# Show Form2 on Excel event BeforeSave

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel-interop

In Visual Studio 2017 I'm creating a Windows Form Application with a `Form1` where the user picks an opened Excel workbook to listen to its `BeforeSave` event.

Once that workbook is saved, it gets detected by the program which then colects some specific data from the sheets and opens `Form2` with that data.

The issue I'm having is that when I load `Form2` on the `BeforeSave` event, its controls (like Labels, buttons, textboxes, etc) don't show correctly. They appear like boxes with a background color.

Here's my code reduced and changed to the part that matters:

```
' Reference:
' Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private xlApp As Excel.Application
    Public Shared WithEvents xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Private Shared Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles xlBook.BeforeSave
        Form2.Show()
        'Form1.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            xlApp = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks(1)
        Catch
            MsgBox("Excel isn't opened.")
            Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit:** Using `Application.Run(Form2)` works (don't know why) but then I also can't close `Form1` with `Form1.Close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeforeSave` event *like the other `Interop.Excel` events* is raised on a different thread. Therefore, you can't access the GUI thread directly from it. In order to access the GUI thread (e.g., access form controls, create a form on the main thread, etc.), you need to call the `Invoke` method with a delegate.

Replacing `Form2.Show()` with the following would solve the problem:

```
Invoke(Sub() Form2.Show())
```

However, you should create a *new* instance of the form that you want to load. So, instead of the previous line,  you should use something like the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(SaveAsUI As Boolean,
                                ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles xlBook.BeforeSave
    Invoke(Sub()
               Dim frm As New Form2
               frm.Show()
           End Sub)
End Sub
```

To learn more about WinForms thread-safe calls, check the first article in the references.

---

### References:

- [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)
- [Why is there a default instance of every form in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698538/4934172)

Comment: Can I keep the `xlBook` `Shared`? I need to use it on the `Form2` class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you were using a Shared variable. Actually, it doesn't have to be declared as Shared in order to access it from another form. You can call `frm.Show(me)` and then access the `xlBook` variable in Form2 using  `DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1).xlBook` or you can pass the variable to the created instance of Form2 by having another public field/property there.

Comment: Thanks, that should do it.