# New form "is never disposed" message

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I've recently moved over to Visual Studio 2019 V16.2 and it's now showing me a new "message" whenever I move between forms in my Windows Forms App.

`IDE0067    Disposable object created by 'New FindFile' is never disposed`

I've always moved to the "next" form in my project with code snippets like:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim frmFindFile As New FindFile
    frmFindFile.Show()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be disposing of the form variable once the new one is showing? The below gets rid of the warning, but my second form never shows up!

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim frmFindFile As New FindFile
    frmFindFile.Show()
    Me.Close()
    frmFindFile.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `Me.Dispose` then? not sure if this is the correct way to do it though

Comment: No - it's complaining about the new object created in the first line - frmFindFile

Comment: Ah right, didn't read it correctly. But you shouldn't dispose of the new form as long as you need it, only when you're done with it.

Comment: Sure, and there are several places in the forms code where it closes itself - which should also dispose of it?

Comment: If you need the form again i would suggest to `hide()` it instead of closing it. If you don't need it again you can dispose it, but make sure no other forms hold a reference to it and might try to access it. I think the garbage collector will automatically dispose of it for you if there are no references to the object anymore. but i think someone more experienced can answer your question better than me tbh.

Comment: VB.NET has default instances of forms, so if you just use `FindFile.Show()`, does it stop complaining? Also, FWIW, I don't see that warning in VS2019 Version 16.3.0 Preview 1.0. P.S. Remember to set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) as the default for new projects as it comes set to Off.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it - somehow seems lazy, but it's obviously the prefferred way of doing it - ping it down as an answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: @MartinKS I'm not sure it's the *preferred* way of doing it, but I added a reference to further information in my answer for your perusal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET has default instances of forms, so if you just use `FindFile.Show()` it will not give a warning.

For more information, please see the answers at [Why is there a default instance of every form in VB.Net but not in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698538/1115360)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the proper answer to this question yet, but there is one.

Original code as listed above is:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim frmFindFile As New FindFile
    frmFindFile.Show()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Yet, the proper way to do this is:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Using frmFindFile As FindFile = New FindFile()
        frmFindFile.Show()
    End Using
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

This will automatically dispose of anything within the Using structure that requires disposal.

Pretty much anything that can be instantiated using the Dim/As class structure can be placed within a Using structure.

Another example would be using streamreader/writer.  Instantiate it with the Using, then instead of using instance.Close(), just use End Using to close it out and dispose of it.