# VB.Net Public Property Return Blank Value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm New in Programming, i can't identify some bugs/error if the Application doesn't tell me where's the error is. So the case is i Code Public Property in purpose to show Text (ID) from FormLogin TextBox into A Lable in another form (FormInputTimeSheet) to Retrieve some data from SQL Server by referring to the ID (i'm using word NIK for ID).

In FromLogin

```
        Dim FIT As New FormInputTimeSheet
        FIT.NIKLookup2 = FlTbNIK.Text
        Me.Hide()
        FormInputTimeSheet.Show()
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success! Selamat Datang " & table.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
```

FlTbNIK is the TextBox i'm using to type ID for Login

In FormInputTimeSheet

```
Public Property NIKLookup2 As String

Private Sub FormInputTimeSheet_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FiLbNIK.Text = NIKLookup2
End Sub
```

FiLbNIK is the target Label and the result is Blank on the Label FiLbNIK

but in the same project i'm using same procedure but it worked, it is successed to show the ID from TextBox in FormLogin to Label in FormEditPassword, here is the code

In FormLogin

```
        Dim FEP As New FormEditPassword
        FEP.NIKLookup1 = FlTbNIK.Text
        FEP.NameLookup = FlLbName.Text
        Me.Hide()
        FEP.Show()
```

In FormEditPassword

```
Public Property NIKLookup1 As String
Public Property NameLookup As String
Private Sub FormEditPassword_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FeLbEpHlp.Visible = False
    FeLbNIK.Text = NIKLookup1
    FeLbName.Text = NameLookup
End Sub
```

These Codes Worked and Showed the ID & Name.

Any Solution would be Appriciated.
Thank before.

Comment: Change _FormInputTimeSheet.Show()_ to _FIT.Show()_ You are displaying the [default form instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c) (something that in my opinion should not exist at all) instead of the instance of the FormInputTimeSheet where you have set the NIK

Comment: omg that one mistake took me hours browsing, Thank you Steve !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what Steve Had Answered from the comment, the error has been Solved by Changing

```
    Dim FIT As New FormInputTimeSheet
    FIT.NIKLookup2 = FlTbNIK.Text
    Me.Hide()
    ***FormInputTimeSheet.Show()***
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success! Selamat Datang " & table.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
```

To

```
    Dim FIT As New FormInputTimeSheet
    FIT.NIKLookup2 = FlTbNIK.Text
    Me.Hide()
    ***FIT.Show()***
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success! Selamat Datang " & table.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
```

Thanks Steve!