# Using a variable from one private sub in another private sub, but both are in the same class

Tags: vb.net, global-variables

In Public Class Main I have this:

```
Public Class Main
    Private targetSheet As String
    Private targetStack As String

    'STACK 1
    Private Sub Stack1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Stack1.Click

        'Set stack and "target stack" aka where to store all changes
        StackOffsetAdjust1.SetWhichStack(1)
        ' other code that doesn't matter
    End Sub
'other code that doesn't matter
End Class
```

and then in the StackOffsetAdjust1 form I have this:

```
Public Class StackOffsetAdjust1
    Public targetStack As Integer

    Public Sub SetWhichStack(ByVal sheetNumber As Integer)
        targetStack = sheetNumber 'pass integer (sheetnumber) to variable targetstack
        MsgBox("targetstack is " & targetStack)
    End Sub

    'APPLY BUTTON
    Private Sub OkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ApplyButton.Click

        Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
        xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        ' The path to the Excel file you want to open
        xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Projects\StackOffsetData.xlsx", [ReadOnly]:=False)

        MsgBox(" using this sheet: " & targetStack)

        xlsheet = CType(xlworkbook.Worksheets(targetStack), Excel.Worksheet)
        
       'more code that doesnt matter right now
     End Sub
'other code that doesnt matter right now
End Class
```

Basically, you're presented with the main form. You click the Stack1 button and that assigns a 1 to the targetstack variable so later in the code it can let it know which excel sheet to store the data on.

My dilemma is that if I hardcode a 1 in there it works perfectly. Also all of those msgbox prompts say 1 so I know it's making it that far with no issues-- except the msgbox inside of Okbutton_click, that one says 0. It looks like it's just not making it into the Private Sub OkButton_Click for some reason. Please help me figure out where I went wrong with this.

I've tried making all of the subs public
I thought I properly declared the variable as a global one, but now I'm not sure at all.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are a victim of the _default form instance_ You can read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c

Comment: How is the form StackOffsetAdjust1 shown?

Comment: The form StackOffsetAdjust1 opens when you click the Stack1 button in the main form