# Error message on shutdown - from unshown winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, operating-system, shutdown

My Winforms Application (consisting of multiple forms), throws an unexpected error during shutdown.
The error is from a form that is not shown to the user (frm.show is not done) at any point of time.
Upon checking the logs, I found that the form was receiving 'WM_QUERYENDSESSION' from the OS.
Why was the unshown form receiving window messages?

Comment: It seems that something in the code is causing an instance of the form to be created, even though it isn't shown.  I'd suggest to either stop that from happening or harden the form against the actual usage that you have.  Running under a debugger may help you find the actual problem with more specificity than just "it received WM_QUERYENDSESSION".

Comment: Why would you have a form that is never shown? Why not post the form code and indicate the line where the exception is thrown? Why not post the exact error message?

Comment: @HardCode apologies for the ambiguity. When I say 'unshown form', I mean that that the form was not shown to the user, but an instance of the form was kept in memory.  Unexpectedly, form was receiving messages from OS. Aren’t only forms that are shown supposed to receive window messages?

Comment: @Craig - thank you for the suggestion. We followed the debugging approach and fortunately were able to solve the issue with some workarounds, but could not find the root cause. During debugging, we did not come across a scenario where the form in question was being instantiated.

Comment: Keep in mind, all VB.NET WinForms Forms have a default instance during runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698538/why-is-there-a-default-instance-of-every-form-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c