Invoke and System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker delegate doesn t work
i have a QRCode scanning project with 2 Forms, form2 opens up after an IF loop in form1, as long as the condition is filled it opens form2 with different data (from different codes) until here everything is right, i want to add a condition that when a new code is scanned and new data is received the already open Form2 is automatically closed before showing the next one
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)  
{       
    if (Form2 != null && !Form2.IsDisposed && Form2.Visible && Form.ActiveForm == Form2)
    {               
        Form2.Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker) delegate{ Form2.Close(); });
    }
}      
else
{
    // ...rest of the code
}       

I also tried creating a bool variable and affect the return to it and calling it in an IF loop --> No luck
i also tried creating a public bool and called the void in an if --> No luck
public bool IsStartScannerOpen;
public bool isOpen;

define "doesn't work"; what happens? if you debug, do you actually get into the Form2.Invoke(...) path?

it doesn t close Form2. Each new scan opens up a new form2(until here it s right) but i have lots of them open when i need one at the time. no it doesn t reach the form2.invoke

Form frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault(); if (frm is object) frm.Invoke(new Action(() => frm.Close())); ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699360/17034
